# Ideals in strong Bruhat order

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, posets, coxeter-groups

Recall that a (lower) ideal in a poset  $(P, \le)$ is a subset $I\subset P$ such that $x\in I \Rightarrow y\in I$ for all $y\le x$. In am interested in ideals in finite Coxeter groups $W$ equipped with the strong Bruhat order $\le$. Specifically, call an ideal $I\subset (W, \le)$ **balanced** if $$W= w_oI\sqcup I$$ where $w_o\in W$ is the longest element. This notion appeared in my work with Bernhard Leeb and Joan Porti on discrete subgroups of semisimple Lie groups.

I wonder if this concept was used earlier in the combinatorics literature. (I know few papers on ideals in the strong Bruhat order, but could not find anything related to the question.)

Comment: Are they possible to describe in the case $W = (A_1)^n$? There $I$ is a simplicial complex.

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Even this case (which corresponds to moduli spaces of planar polygons as you well know) I do not know how to handle. There are balanced ideals coming from GIT (choices of polygonal side-lengths which are not on "walls": the "balanced" condition amounts to "stable=semistable" situation). I am sure there are other balanced ideals as well, but I do not know how to find them.

Comment: Why, so it does! (For everyone else: given a generic list $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of positive reals, let $I = \{S \subseteq [n]\ :\ \sum_S a_s < \sum_{[n]\setminus S} a_s\}$. Then $I$ is a balanced ideal for $(A_1)^n$.)

Comment: For small root systems these could be enumerated by brute force.  Should I assume this wouldn't be satisfactory for the purposes of your question?  That is, you want some structure theory?

Comment: @DavidDumas: yes, exactly. For instance, asymptotics of how many as rank tends to infinity.